# Object as $http params

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to make a GET request to an API using angulars `$http` service with having an object as an url parameter, but it doesn't really work as expected.

Expected result:

```
http://something.com/test?page=20&filter=hello
```

Effective outcome (copied from app):

```
api/cameras?query=%7B%22filterByFields%22:%7B%7D,%22page%22:0,%22pageSize%22:20%7D
```

which translates to:

```
{"filterByFields":{},"page":0,"pageSize":20}
```

According to angulars documentation on the `params` usage:

> Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters.

**cameraApiService**

```
public getCameras(query) {
        var deferred = this._q.defer();
        this._http.get(this._baseUrl, {
            params: {
                query: query
            }
        })
        .success((result, status, headers) => 
                deferred.resolve({
                    items:      result.items,
                    page:       result.page,
                    pageSize:   result.pageSize,
                    totalCount: result.total
                })
            )
        .error((msg, code) => {
            deferred.reject(msg);
            console.error(code, msg);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

**cameraListController**

```
public loadData() {
        this.loaded     = false;
        this.items      = [];

        var options = {
            filter:         this.filter,
            filterByFields: this.filterByFields,
            orderBy:        this.orderBy,
            page:           this.page,
            pageSize:       this.pageSize
        };

        this._cameraApi.getCameras(options)
            .then(result => {
                this.items          = result.items;
                this.totalCount     = result.totalCount;
                this.pageSize       = result.pageSize;
                this.page           = result.page;
                this.loaded         = true;
            }, error => {
                this._toaster.pop({ type: "error", body: "Unknown error occured: " + error });
                this.loaded  = true;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Can you copy the code exactly, please? What you have written is missing the closing ')'  for `get` so wouldn't work at all. It's hard to guess what the problem is if we don't know what the code is.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a mistake

Instead of

```
this._http.get(this._baseUrl, {
   params: {
     query: query
   }
})
```

pass directly your query object to params like this

```
this._http.get(this._baseUrl, {
    params: query
})
```

normally it should work.

Comment: Bingo! He's creating an object nested in another. And according to `$httpParamSerializer` if there's an object nested in the object, it just encodes the JSON instead of trying to figure it out. Good catch.

Comment: Yes it serialized directly the object linked to the `params` key

Answer (score 0):

I think "params" should be JSON.stringify

```
var query= JSON.stringify({
    params: {
        page:     page,
        filter:   filterField, 
    }
});
```

then:

```
$http({
  method:'GET',
  url:baseuri + "test",
  query
});
```